findDOMNode is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release
i am getting this error=> findDOMNode is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference. I am using vite.
import React from 'react'
import { useEffect, useState , useRef} from "react"
import axios from "axios"

function Trending() {
   const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
   const [content, setContent] = useState([]);

const fetchTrending = async () => {
   const { data } = await axios.get(
  `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/all/day?        api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}&page=${page}`
  );

   setContent(data.results);
};

useEffect(() => {
   window.scroll(0, 0);
  fetchTrending();
}, [page]);


   return (
      <div>Trending</div>
   )
}

export default Trending
